# Does patch.multiple work with pytest as a decorator

Tags: python, pytest, python-mock

I have a `test_tmp.py` adopted from https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-multiple

```
from unittest.mock import DEFAULT, MagicMock, patch

thing = object()
other = object()

@patch.multiple('__main__', thing=DEFAULT, other=DEFAULT)
def test_function(thing, other):
    print(f'thing={thing}')
    print(f'other={other}')
    assert isinstance(thing, MagicMock)
    assert isinstance(other, MagicMock)

test_function()
```

It runs with python

```
python test_tmp.py
thing=<MagicMock name='thing' id='4355085552'>
other=<MagicMock name='other' id='4355243312'>
```

but it doesn't work with pytest with error like

```
pytest test_tmp.py
============================================================================================================= test session starts =============================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /private/tmp
collected 0 items / 1 error

=================================================================================================================== ERRORS ====================================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_tmp.py _________________________________________________________________________________________________________
test_tmp.py:13: in <module>
    test_function()
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1345: in patched
    with self.decoration_helper(patched,
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py:113: in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1313: in decoration_helper
    arg = patching.__enter__()
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1416: in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/unittest/mock.py:1389: in get_original
    raise AttributeError(
E   AttributeError: <module '__main__' from '/path/to/bin/pytest'> does not have the attribute 'thing'
=========================================================================================================== short test summary info ===========================================================================================================
ERROR test_tmp.py - AttributeError: <module '__main__' from '/path/to/bin/pytest'> does not have the attribute 'thing'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================================================================================================== 1 error in 0.31s ===============================================================================================================
```

wondering why?

I'm using pytest = "^5.4.3"

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things here that won't work in pytest:

- you cannot directly call a test, so calling that function will not work
- the decorator version doesn't work in this case, I guess `pytest` just does not implement this (pytest by default understands test function arguments as fixtures; it handles position arguments used by `patch` and `patch.object` correctly, but seems not to be able to handle the keyword arguments injected by `patch.multiple`)
- using `'__main__'` may not work, you can use `sys.modules[__name__]` instead.

So this is a working version:

```py
def test_function1():
    with patch.multiple(sys.modules[__name__],
                        thing=DEFAULT,
                        other=DEFAULT) as mocks:
        print(f'thing = {mocks["thing"]}')
        print(f'other = {mocks["other"]}')
        assert isinstance(thing, MagicMock)
        assert isinstance(other, MagicMock)
```

This version should also work with `unittest`.

In pytest, you usually would move this kind of mocking into a fixture, so this is probably more in the pytest spirit:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def multiple():
    with patch.multiple(sys.modules[__name__],
                        thing=DEFAULT,
                        other=DEFAULT) as mocks:
        yield mocks


def test_function(multiple):
    print(f'thing = {multiple["thing"]}')
    print(f'other = {multiple["other"]}')
    assert isinstance(thing, MagicMock)
    assert isinstance(other, MagicMock)
```

*Note:*
This does only answer the question in the title, not the "why" - I had a look at the source code of `patch.multiple`, but didn't understand how it interacts with pytest. Maybe someone with more insight can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

in conftest you can do either of these:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    # Patching the first function
    with patch('module.function1') as mock_function1:
        mock_function1.return_value = 'Mocked result for function1'

        # Patching the second function
        with patch('module.function2') as mock_function2:
            mock_function2.return_value = 'Mocked result for function2'

            # Yield the fixture
            yield mock_function1, mock_function2

# Test using the fixture
def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    mock_function1, mock_function2 = my_fixture

    # Test code using the mocked functions
    result1 = module.function1()  # This will use the mock
    result2 = module.function2()  # This will use the other mock

    assert result1 == 'Mocked result for function1'
    assert result2 == 'Mocked result for function2'
```

Or you can do two separate fixtures and pass them both into another function.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def patched_check():
    with patch('core.management.commands.wait_for_db.Command.check') as p:
        yield p
    logging.info("patched_check finished")

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def time_sleep():
    with patch('time.sleep') as p:
        yield p
    logging.info("patched_check finished")

def wait_delay(patched_check, time_sleep):
    pass
```

Second example was from my code that mocks `time.sleep` and `core.management.commands.wait_for_db.Command.check`